# Only a portion of string is written to the file using WriteLine

Tags: vbscript, text-files, export-to-csv

I have following script:

```
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
outFile="C:\Temp\export.csv"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,2,True)
objFile.WriteLine([SQLtoCSV])
objFile.Close
SET WriteStuff = NOTHING
SET objFSO = NOTHING
```

The variable [SQLtoCSV] is equal to:

> "Id","AanmaakDatum","Stofnaam","Samenstelling","Kleurcode","Pictogrammen","Signaalwoord","Hnummers","Pnummers","Opslag","AantalTHT","THTCode","Eigenaar","PBMPictogrammen","MSDS"
>   "1431","","Koperoxide - CuO","keramiek","Geel","GHS09","WAARSCHUWING","H400","P273-P391-P501","","0","Dag","SASK","PBM01-PBM03-PBM07","2015"
>   "1432","","Nikkelcarbonaat","keramiek","Rood","GHS07-GHS08-GHS09","GEVAAR","H315-H317-H341-H302-H332-H372-H360D-H350i-H334-H410","P261-P270-P273-P362-P308 + P313","","0","Dag","SASK","PBM01-PBM03-PBM07","2015"
>   "1433","","Aluminiumhydroxide","keramiek","Groen","","WEINIG GEVAAR","","","gesloten op droge plaats","0","Dag","SASK","PBM01-PBM03","2015"
>   "1427","","Nikkeloxide","keramiek","Rood","GHS07-GHS08","GEVAAR","H317-H350-H372-H413","P201-P202-P260-P261-P264-P270-P272-P273-P280-P302 + P352-P308 + P313-P333 + P313-P314-P405-P501-P321-P363","kast voor stoffen - gesloten","0","Dag","SASK","PBM03-PBM05-PBM07","2015
>   "

My problem is that only the first 2 lines are written on the txt file:

> Id,"AanmaakDatum","Stofnaam","Samenstelling","Kleurcode","Pictogrammen","Signaalwoord","Hnummers","Pnummers","Opslag","AantalTHT","THTCode","Eigenaar","PBMPictogrammen","MSDS"
>   1431,"","Koperoxide - CuO","keramiek","Geel","GHS09","WAARSCHUWING","H400","P273-P391-P501","","0","Dag","SASK","PBM01-PBM03-PBM07","2015

I can't find out why it is acting like this.
Does anyone has an idea?

**EDIT:**

I get the variable through a SQL command :

```
SELECT * FROM StadRoe_LabelData
```

Result is stored in the variable [SQLtoCSV] :

> "Id","AanmaakDatum","Stofnaam","Samenstelling","Kleurcode","Pictogrammen","Signaalwoord","Hnummers","Pnummers","Opslag","AantalTHT","THTCode","Eigenaar","PBMPictogrammen","MSDS"
>   "1431","","Koperoxide - CuO","keramiek","Geel","GHS09","WAARSCHUWING","H400","P273-P391-P501","","0","Dag","SASK","PBM01-PBM03-PBM07","2015
>   "
>   "1432","","Nikkelcarbonaat","keramiek","Rood","GHS07-GHS08-GHS09","GEVAAR","H315-H317-H341-H302-H332-H372-H360D-H350i-H334-H410","P261-P270-P273-P362-P308 + P313","","0","Dag","SASK","PBM01-PBM03-PBM07","2015
>   "
>   "1433","","Aluminiumhydroxide","keramiek","Groen","","WEINIG GEVAAR","","","gesloten op droge plaats","0","Dag","SASK","PBM01-PBM03","2015
>   "
>   "1427","","Nikkeloxide","keramiek","Rood","GHS07-GHS08","GEVAAR","H317-H350-H372-H413","P201-P202-P260-P261-P264-P270-P272-P273-P280-P302 + P352-P308 + P313-P333 + P313-P314-P405-P501-P321-P363","kast voor stoffen - gesloten","0","Dag","SASK","PBM03-PBM05-PBM07","2015
>   "

I'm using NiceLabel to execute those commands

Comment: Use `Write()` instead of `WriteLine()` is the result different?

Comment: I copied what you say is the value of `SQLtoCSV` and pasted it into an empty file, used `objFSO.OpenTextFile` to read the contents of that file, then I ran your code and couldn't reproduce your problem. Please show us how you obtain `SQLtoCSV` and what its actual value is. In other words, please provide a [repro].

Comment: What is the type of that variable, and how did you populate it?

Comment: I edited my post with the correct syntax of the result of the query. It should be a string

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I edited my post with the exact syntax. Looks like it stops when encountering the double quote on one line.

Comment: @Jeremy It's good that you solved your own problem. Stack Overflow strictly separates questions and answers. We don't put answers in questions. You've already added an answer with the information (which is encouraged). I've rolled-back the edit you made which added the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem by formatting the result like this before putting it to my textfile :

```
a = Replace([SQLtoCSV],"""","")
b = Split(a, vbCrLf)
[SQLtoCSV] = ""
for each x in b
    If x <> "" Then
        [SQLtoCSV] = [SQLtoCSV] & x & vbCrLf
    End If
next
```